# Catching logger output Junit

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4

I need to write a unit test for this method (for code coverage purposes).

```
public void post(LexileResults lexileResults) {
        try {
            restClient.postForObject(saveEndpoint,
                lexileResults, LexileResults.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(String.format("Exception thrown for post: {0}", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

The class that contains this method has a logger property that looks like this:

```
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

The problem is that I don't want to throw an exception here. We don't really care much if the post fails. Our process will post it again. So all I want to assert is that we log something when restClient.postForObject throws an exception.

This is what I tried:

```
@Test
public void testServicePostWithException() {
        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(ForecastingService.class);

        // create and start a ListAppender
        ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
        listAppender.start();

        // add the appender to the logger
        logger.addAppender(listAppender);

        final LexileResults result = mock(LexileResults.class);
        RestClientException exception = new RestClientException("something went wrong");
        when(restClient.postForObject(Mockito.any(),
            Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenThrow(exception);
        instance.post(result);

        List<ILoggingEvent> logsList = listAppender.list;
        assertTrue(listAppender.list.contains("Exception thrown for post"));

        listAppender.stop();
        logger.detachAppender(listAppender);
    }
```

but my assertion fails.
If I try to do something like this: `assertEquals("start", logsList.get(0).getMessage());`, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` exception.

Why isn't my listAppender catching logger output?

Comment: `listAppender.list` is a list of `ILoggingEvent`, but you check whether it contains a `String`

Comment: Your test doesn't define `restClient` so, as is, it would not compile. Is there more in your test that should be included?

Comment: restClient is an instance of `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`